# bind function with arguments from controller to directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind a function with arguments from a controller to a directive using angular 1.4.

My directive looks like this:

```
var InvoiceSearchController = function() {
    this.searchCriteriaChanged("test");
};

var invoiceSearchComonent = ['invoiceDataService', function (invoiceDataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: path.fromRoot("/application/invoices/views/invoicesearch.html"),
        controller: InvoiceSearchController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: {
            searchCriteriaChanged: '&'
         }
     };
}];

module.directive('invoicesearch', invoiceSearchComonent);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
module.controller('contractorsInvoiceCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'invoiceDataService', function($scope, $timeout, invoiceDataService) {
    $scope.onSearchCriteriaChanged = function(args) {
        console.log(args);
     };
}]);
```

And in my template I call it try to bind like this:

```
<invoicesearch search-criteria-changed="onSearchCriteriaChanged(args)"></invoicesearch>
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for
>   'onSearchCriteriaChanged' in test

How can I bind a function from the controller to directive with arguments.  I think I am missing something fundamental.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XGjGSCj48s58L5aOsOll?p=preview) that shows the issue

Comment: Can you please add any Fiddle/Plnkr?

Comment: @KhalidHussain I have added a plnkr that shows the issue

Answer (score 0):

Into your template , try to pass your args as an object , like :

```
<invoicesearch search-criteria-changed="onSearchCriteriaChanged({value:args})"></invoicesearch>
```

**into controller**

```
$scope.onSearchCriteriaChanged = function(value) {
        //manipulate value object
     };
```

### Update

I created an example , that has a `<select>` element into a custom directive and whenever the user chooses a value from the dropbox, it passes the selected object to the controller while it calls the controller's function.

### directive

```
.directive('eventHallsList', function($timeout, $log, $http, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        changeHall: '&',
        items: '=',
        model: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'mytemplate.tpl.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      }

    }
```

mytemplate.tpl.html

```
<select style="color:#337ab7"
        ng-change="changeHall({value:model})" ng-model="model"
        ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
    <option value=""> choose hall</option>
</select>
```

---

live: http://plnkr.co/edit/iCS0blQjceA4tIIb8bUV?p=preview

hope helps good luck.

Comment: same result as before

Comment: strange im gonna create an example.

Comment: where is eventHallsList used?

Comment: It's a custom directive(from my web-app) that is transformed to a <select> element. Json object is passed into directive and each time you change the selected value, 1. the ng-model is passed as a parameter to a function (which is into the controller)   2. the $scope.selectedObj is updated with the selected item

Answer (score 0):

The way I got this working was to pass an object that had a property that matched the name of the arguments specified in the template.  In the template I am specifying that I am passing an `args` object.

```
<invoicesearch search-criteria-changed="onSearchCriteriaChanged(args)" contractors="contractors"></invoicesearch>
```

Then when I call the bound function in the directive controller, I make sure it has a property called `args`:

```
  var myArgs = {foo: 'bar'};
  this.searchCriteriaChanged({args: myArgs});
```

Not sure if this is any better in angular 1.5 but I found this very unintuitive.